# Authorization for pre-signed url generate api?

Tags: amazon-s3, authorization, pre-signed-url

Our application only have Front End and Back End. Each user can have a lot of document which is uploaded by backend side but need to be display on FE. We trying to use pre-signed URL to let FE download document directly from S3.

BE return the document's path, and expose an API which can be use to generate pre-signed url for each document.

```
POST: /app/v1/generate-pre-signed-url/path-to-document
```

The issue is above generate pre-signed url API need to be verity that current user has access to the document or not, and it's really hard to map the user permission with a document path.

Any suggestion design or pattern would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As per [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

> When you create a presigned URL for your object, you must provide your security credentials and then specify a bucket name, an object key, an HTTP method (GET to download the object), and an expiration date and time.

So in summary, only object key would not suffice (like in your case).